# Как изменять стиль drawer activity

Tags: android, style, android-navigation-drawer

Как сделать свой стиль Drawer Activity? Например изменить цвет items, добавить свои иконки, место между items и др

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду DrawerLayout с выдвигающейся шторкой? Не слышал ни разу об DrawerActivity если честно.

Comment: @YaPV да, я имел ввиду то, о чем вы говорите. В android studio он называется navigation drawer activity

Comment: А я наверное понял тогда, про что говорите вы. Нужно понять, что последний Layout который лежит в корневом DrawerLayout и будет являться вашей выдвижной шторкой.

В своем примере я в корневой DrawerLayout добавлял последний элементом FrameLayout,соответственно моя выдвижная шторка была фрагментом, который я отрисовывал по собственному желанию. В моем случае в фрагменте был простейший список, который и отображался в шторке потом. Весьма удобно и просто на самом деле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую дать ответ xml разметкой, может так нагляднее будет:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Получается, что я создавал свой кастомный тулбар, а под ним распологал `DrawerLayout`, в фрагменте `id=content_frame` отображалось содержимое главного экрана при входе в приложение, а в фрагменте `id=navigation_frame`, отображалось содержимое моей выдвижной шторки.

Важно заметить, что выдвижная шторка при таком раскладе xml разметки не будет залазить на тулбар. Мне это было необходимо, это я и сделал :)

Если отвечать конкретно по вашему вопросу, то попробуйте в в фрагменте `id=navigation_frame` отрисовать список (`listview` или `recyclerview`), который через адаптер принимает `item` любого дизайна, который придет вам в голову.